# Regex to match values between substrings where the middle values are all the same character

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to standardise a set of text files that contain a list of values separated by pipes ("|") which currently have varying decimal places for values with trailing zeros.

This seems like something that a regex should be able to handle but I'm struggling with where to start. I've found examples where I can replace any values between two sets of substrings, but not an example where it only matches when the values between are all the same character.

The Python code below shows a minimal example of what I'm trying to achieve (where the assert should pass if the replacement is successful). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import re

str_in = '4|5|0.00000000|'
expected_str_out = '4|5|0.0|'

str_out = re.sub('0.(.*?)\|', '0.0|', s)
assert str_out == expected_str_out
```

Comment: So, what is the `regex` you are using now? `{regex}` cannot match any number. Do you mean to say `11111.111111` should be replaced with `1.1`? What if there is `.5555`?

Comment: `0.(.*?)\|` is one of the examples I've tested which works in this example but would also incorrectly match if `str_in = '4|5|0.00other_characters00|'`. I put `{regex}` to represent where I am inputting the expression.

I am only looking to match where the repeated characters are 0s

Comment: Ok, I added it into the question, please add some more explanation of the behavior and add the expected behavior (the test must be true, I guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re

str_in = '4|5|0.00000000|'
expected_str_out = '4|5|0.0|'

str_out = re.sub(r'(?<![^|])0+\.0+(?![^|])', '0.0', str_in)
print( str_out == expected_str_out )
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/EgPR15) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fAmRmG/2).

The regex matches

- `(?<![^|])` - start of string or a `|`
- `0+\.0+` - one or more `0` chars, `.` and one or more `0`s
- `(?![^|])` - an end of string, or `|`.

In case you need to handle cases like `2.2222`, `333.333`, `5555555.55` you can use

```
(?<![^|])(\d)\1*\.\1+(?![^|])
```

Replace with `\1.\1`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fAmRmG/3).

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for this. As mentioned in the question I'm only looking to match "when the values between are all the same character", unfortunately with this regex it also matches if I have say `str_in = '4|5|0.00007000|'`.

Comment: @AyrtonBourn What do you mean? My solution [does not match `4|5|0.00007000|`](https://regex101.com/r/fAmRmG/4).

Comment: An error on my part, can confirm this is now working. Thank you very much

Comment: One last Q if possible @wiktor-stribiżew. How would I modify this regex such that it ignores the number in front of the decimal place? I.e. 1.0000 -> 1.0. I've tried modifying the negative look-behind but had no luck.

Comment: @AyrtonBourn See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fAmRmG/5). `re.sub(r'(?<![^|])(?:(0)+|(\d+))\.0+(?![^|])', r'\1\2.0', text)`